# no power what so ever anywhere after replacing battery fuse box & battery ground harness.and battery

Tags: vw

After fuse box on top of battery melted i replaced it also alt was replaced. i noticed the battery ground harness was very corroded so i replaced it too. i then had to buy a new battery after doing all of this,within a matter of 4 weeks car has 256,000 miles i installed the battery and get in to start car and no power to anything!i am at a loss on what to check next. the car is a 2004 vw 2.0L jetta wagon.

Comment: if your fuse box melted, you need to check your entire wiring loom - it's a sign something went badly wrong...

Comment: i am getting power to fuse box but no power to dash,ignition,anything inside no lights nadda

Answer (score 1):

Make sure there is no corrosion in side the positive and negative wires, there should be no bumps or warped looking rubber around them, if there is then split the rubber and clean it out further and electrical tape it back up.

Id check fuses under the steering wheel as well. Get a fuse light tester and turn ignition on and see if anything turns that light on.

If not then maybe take it to a professional to have a look at it because  you might have short and thats difficult to find.